# Confusion in call by copy-restore in a special case

Tags: function-calls

I understand the basic logic of call by copy restore. But I was wondering for a problem like this

```
void p(int x,int y) {
     x++;
     y+=2;
}

main() {
   int a=10;
   p(a,a);
   // what will be now value of a, 11 or 12?
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running this?  Is this supposed to be C or something else?  In C the value of `a` will be 10 (assuming `=++` was intended to be `++`) but I'm not sure I'm clear on what you're asking.  Particularly, what is `x=++` intended to be?  `x++`?

Comment: What language is this? It seems the code doesn't compile either. "x=++" ?

Comment: I am not talking about any language here, I am just asking about call by copy restore method.

Comment: Neither. After that call, you will still have `a==10`. `x` and `y` within `p()` are *copies* of `a`, and changes to them are not back-propagated...

Comment: I am pretty sure in copy-restore method it will be either 11 or 12 but the confusion is which value will be the final one.

Comment: Perhaps you'll need to explain this "copy-restore method", and where you heard about it. It's not something that is in the C or C++ languages, which have call-by-value and call-by-reference. Perhaps this is a different language you are talking about (although the posted code appears to at least be an approximation of C)?

Comment: @alienCoder When you are talking about copy-restore, you **are** talking about a language, because most languages don't support copy-restore. Posting a code sample in your question that looks like C (a language that does not support copy-restore) is a bit misleading. A few more details would have made this a really great question!

Comment: @alienCoder I think you got your answer down there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**: The answer is 12, see update below.

OK, this is actually a good question. So this explains what "copy-restore" is all about: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8871340/171933

Most programming languages don't support copy/restore, but only (some variations) of pass-by-value and pass-by-reference. So it's not so easy to try this out.

However, the question you are interested in is this: Which value wins? Does `x` get to write its value back to `a` when the function ends (which would be 11), or does `y` get to write its value back to `a` when the function ends (which would be 12).

In a language that supports "copy-restore", I'd hope that this would throw a compiler error.

**Update**:

After some searching I've found a language that actually supports "copy-restore", namely Ada. This is the code in Ada (this is my first and probably last program written in Ada):

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure copy_restore_example is
        a: integer;

        procedure p(x: in out integer; y: in out integer) is
        begin
                x:= x+1;
                y:= y+2;
        end p;

begin
        a := 10;
        Put_Line("Before :" & natural'image(a));
        p(a, a);
        Put_Line("After :" & natural'image(a));

end copy_restore_example;
```

The result is **12**, `y` wins. You can run this program in your browser here: http://www.compileonline.com/compile_ada_online.php