# Call by reference vs call by copy restore

Tags: c

I was looking at call by reference and call by copy/restore. And I had some confusion. Suppose I have a 2-parameter function that increments 1 to each parameter. Now what will happen if I use both the parameters as the same variable, like `incr(i, i)`, in the case of call by reference and call by copy/restore?

Comment: C only has 'pass by value'.  Therefore, you'd have to simulate 'pass by reference' by passing a pointer, and I'm not sure what semantics you expect from copy/restore; too much depends on who does the copying and who does the restoring.  Maybe Wikipedia's [Evaluation Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy) article can help; it has a section on 'call by copy/restore'.

Comment: You might also find [What's the difference between call by reference and copy/restore?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848402/whats-the-difference-between-call-by-reference-and-copy-restore) relevant.  Is there a reason question this should not be closed as a duplicate of that one?

Comment: Yes, I specifically wanted the implementation of both cases with respect to the incr(i,i) function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question [What's the difference between call by reference and copy/restore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848402/whats-the-difference-between-call-by-reference-and-copy-restore) covers this in part, but it isn't quite complete.  The Wikipedia article on [Evaluation Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy) is helpful.

Here are two implementations and calls for a function `incr()` that takes two arguments and increments each one.

#### Call by reference

```
#include <stdio.h>

void incr(int *pi1, int *pi2)
{
    (*pi1)++;
    (*pi2)++;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i = 57;
    printf("%d\n", i);
    incr(&i, &i);
    printf("%d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
57
59
```

#### Call by copy/restore

The `incr` function is actually unchanged from the call by reference version.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void incr(int *pi1, int *pi2)
{
    (*pi1)++;
    (*pi2)++;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i = 57;
    printf("%d\n", i);
    {
    int cr_0000 = i;    // Copy for first argument
    int cr_0001 = i;    // Copy for second argument
    incr(&cr_0000, &cr_0001);
    i = cr_0001;        // Restore for second argument
    i = cr_0000;        // Restore for first argument
    }
    printf("%d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
57
58
```

Note that with this `incr()` function, it does not matter which order the values are restored, but if the `incr()` function treated its arguments asymmetrically (say, added 1 to the first and 2 to the second), then the final result would depend on whether `cr_0000` is restored before `cr_0001` or vice versa.

Comment: Though I get how the output is generated...I don't get the whole point behind copy/restore. Its "make copy of original variable, pass the copies by reference, reassign copies back to the original variable". What's great to give a dedicated name "copy/restore"?

Comment: @Mahesha999 The second one is also call by reference, he's just done something different with it. I hadn't heard it whatsoever until I saw it in some exam paper and I think they made it up